# how to query in order of current date?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to filter according to current date in flask sqlalchemy , below are my codes anytime I run it on the server it keeps giving me errors,can someone please help me.

```
class Ads(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key =True)
    condition = db.Column(db.String(255))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(233))
    category = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    brand = db.Column(db.String(255))
    negotiable = db.Column(db.String(255))
    price = db.Column(db.String(255))
    city = db.Column(db.String(255))
    post_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    image = db.Column(LargeBinary)
    image_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    mimetype =  db.Column(db.String(255))
    post_on = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    

if  selected_page == 'electronics':
                 current_time = datetime.now()
        
                 imb = Ads.query.filter_by(category='electronics',date>= current_date).paginate(per_page=20,page =page,error_out=True)
                 return render_template('electronics.html',imb=imb,prmo=prmo)
```

Comment: What is your exact error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`imb=Ads.query.filter(and_(category=='electronics',date>=current_date)) .paginate(per_page=20,page =page,error_out=True)`

You must import `and_` from sqlalchemy:
`from sqlalchemy import and_`

Use `filter` instead of `filter_by`.

Comment: Fasil it’s says cannot import the name _and from sqlalchemy

Comment: Sorry, there is a small mistake. It's not ````_and```` it's ````and_````

Comment: Fasil please it’s not working

Comment: But when I use <= it works but not according to current date

Comment: use filter instead of filter_by

Comment: What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: I’m not getting any error but it doesn’t show any thing but when I use <= it shows the list but not current

Comment: Fasil can you join me on team viewer

Comment: You ab send the screenshot of your error to my LinkedIn account : https://www.linkedin.com/in/fasil-k